# Java, installation problem or issue of the noob?

Tags: java, netbeans

Hi guys I have tried in recent days to install, obviously everything from termianl, the jdk for Java with no success. 
Later I tried to install WinUSB and everything went ok. 
**Today panic**, I'm going to install AWN and I find errors even when I type sudo apt-get update
I solved these errors, but every time I try to install any application, terminal gives me errors like this.
Down here is the complete code with that mistakes, maybe it happened to any of you, or know how to help me. 
**The big problem** is that I can't install anything else because I always have this error. 
Thank you in advice for your attention and for your help!

I write  sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer

I need java for use Netbeans

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 oracle-java7-installer : Depends: java-common (>= 0.24) but it is not installable
                          Recommends: gsfonts-x11 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

**edited**

```
java-common:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
Linux giovanni-X551CAP 3.19.0-30-generic #34~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Oct 2 22:09:39 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Try a `sudo apt-add-repository main; sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For whatever reason the `main` repository is missing or your package information was deleted or never updated. Execute the following commands:

```
sudo apt-add-repository main
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
```

Answer (score -1):

Purge the foreign ppa and Install openjdk from repository:

```
$ sudo apt install ppa-purge
$ ppa-purge [YOUR PPA]
$ sudo apt install openjdk-7-jre
```